# How to get the value of date from @react-native-community/datetimepicker and store it in for a user in an object

Tags: react-native, react-native-datetimepicker

I am building a signup page for users where they can select their date of birth from the datepicker which I used from '@react-native-community/datetimepicker'. Everything is working fine and the code is able to display the selected date on the screen, also every other field's data is getting stored in the **userInfo** object except the **dateOfBirth**.
Here is the part of code where I used the datepicker:

(You can ignore **formatDate** function as it just formats the date out of timestamp)

```
            <Text style={[styles.text_footer,{marginTop:10}]}>Date Of Birth</Text>
            <View style={[styles.action,{paddingTop:5}]}>
                <FontAwesome
                name="calendar"
                color="#05375a"
                size={20}
                onPress={showDatepicker}
                />
                {show && (
                    <DateTimePicker
                    testID='dateTimePicker'
                    value={date}
                    mode={mode}
                    is24Hour={true}
                    display='default'
                    onChange={onChange}
                    //onChange={(val)=>handleOnChangeText(val,'dateOfBirth')}
                    />
                )}
                <Text style={[styles.textInput,{paddingTop:10}]}>{formatDate(date)}</Text>
            </View>
```

And the functions and states used are:

```
    const [date, setDate] = useState(new Date());
    const [mode, setMode] = useState('date');
    const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

    const [userInfo, setUserInfo]=React.useState({
        email:'',
        password:'',
        gender:'',
        age:null,
        dateOfBirth:'',
        address:'',
        role:'',
        check_textInputChange:false,
        secureTextEntry:true,
        isValidUser: true,
        isValidPassword: true,
        isValidAge:true,
        isValidAddress:true
    });

    const {email,password,gender,age,dateOfBirth,address,role}=userInfo;


    const onChange = (event, selectedValue) => {
        setShow(Platform.OS === 'ios');
        if (mode == 'date') {
          const currentDate = selectedValue || new Date();
          setDate(currentDate);
        } 
      };
    const showMode = currentMode => {
        setShow(true);
        setMode(currentMode);
      };
    const showDatepicker = () => {
        showMode('date');
      };
    const handleOnChangeText= (val,fieldname)=>{
        setUserInfo({...userInfo,[fieldname]:val})
        //console.log(val,fieldname);
    };
//If I console.log(userInfo) here then the state dateOfBirth is not getting updated
```

ALSO, an example of email and how I am using **handleOnChangeText** function:

(THIS IS WORKING. Attached just for understanding purposes, please ignore **textInputChange** and **handleValidUser** functions)

```
            <Text style={styles.text_footer}>Email</Text>
            <View style={styles.action}>
                <FontAwesome
                name="user-o"
                color="#05375a"
                size={20}
                />
                <TextInput
                value={email}
                placeholder="Your Email" 
                style={styles.textInput}
                autoCapitalize="none"
                onChangeText={(val)=>{textInputChange(val);handleOnChangeText(val,'email');}}
                onEndEditing={(e)=>handleValidUser(e.nativeEvent.text)}
                />
                {userInfo.check_textInputChange?
                <Animatable.View
                    animation="bounceIn"
                >
                <Feather
                name="check-circle"
                color="green"
                size={20}
                />
                </Animatable.View>
                :null}
            </View>
            {
                userInfo.isValidUser?null:
            <Animatable.View animation="fadeInLeft" duartion={500}>
             <Text style={styles.errorMsg}>Username must be 4 characters long.</Text>       
             </Animatable.View>
            }
```

The object output after logging userInfo

[image]

How can I get the value of dateOfBirth in userInfo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is likely due to a minor mistake in your code. The [Date change handler](https://github.com/react-native-datetimepicker/datetimepicker#onchange-optional) that you are passing to `DateTimePicker` does never call `handleOnChangeText`:

```
<DateTimePicker
    testID='dateTimePicker'
    value={date}
    mode={mode}
    is24Hour={true}
    display='default'
    onChange={onChange} // <--- this one
    //onChange={(val)=>handleOnChangeText(val,'dateOfBirth')}
/>
```

Updating the handler should solve your problem:

```
const onChange = (event, selectedValue) => {
    setShow(Platform.OS === 'ios');
    if (mode == 'date') {
        const currentDate = selectedValue || new Date();
        setDate(currentDate);
        handleOnChangeText(currentData, 'dateOfBirth') // <--- add this line
    } 
};
```

Comment: Thanks man, it was a silly mistake. Your answer solved my problem :)